# How can I completely reset the Visual Code editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create a bug report for this editor that has some complicated steps, and I need to have a "fresh" install of VS Code.  I've tried uninstalling and deleting user settings, but I'm not getting various prompts that I did when I ran it the first time.

I want all extensions gone, all users settings, everything.

Comment: VMs and checkpoints would be my first suggestion.  Beyond that, you're likely to need to dig through the registry and file system and I doubt you'll find a canonical list anywhere.

Comment: This topic might be useful: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3884

Answer (score 3):

On my Linux box - the only box I currently have :p - there were two places where VSCode stored my settings.

- ~/.config/Code
- ~/.vscode

These could be renamed/deleted.
Provided that you also are a *nix user, of course.

However, I agree with Matthew Wetmore: use a Virtual Machine (VirtualBox, etc.) because that will ensure an 'untainted' system that can be used to reliably reproduce the issue you want to report.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--user-data-dir` CLI option to load an instance with a fresh userdata directory. It will still load extensions from `~/.vscode`, so you can rename that directory.